# skip confirmation e-mail in development with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, email, devise

I am using devise and I want to be able to skip the confirmation e-mail while I am in development mode. Since my application can't send e-mail while running on my local machine, I will just get the alert message saying that you need to be confirmed before accessing the application.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

try Letter Opener gem from Ryan Bates

https://github.com/ryanb/letter_opener

it will open the email in the browser without sending it. You don't want to be skipping stuff out if you're in development because stuff will get missed/forgotten about.

Comment: Not sure about the asker here, but I personally am populating a large app with lots of data. I just had 600+ tabs opened in my browser because I do use letter opener. I agree that in most cases you wouldn't want to skip, in this case I def. need to skip.

Answer (score 29):

Devise has also a method [skip_confirmation!](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Confirmable#skip_confirmation%21-instance_method) that you can call on the model before saving it to avoid sending the mail. It simply sets the `confirmed_at` attribute which results in skipping the mail sending.

Answer (score 13):

As simple as that

```
user=User.new
user.email="you@email.id"
user.password="yourPassword"
user.skip_confirmation!
user.save
```

Comment: Just as a little FYI, you can put all of that in a block: `user = User.new { |u| u.email = 'you@email.id'; u.password = 'yourPassword'; u.skip_confirmation! }.save`.  Blocks are fun!

Answer (score 6):

Or you could try [MailCatcher](https://github.com/sj26/mailcatcher) in your development environment.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a really light weight way to do this, look in your terminal after registering - the rails output shows the email that got sent, you can copy-paste the confirmation link, confirming the account and then continue testing.

crude, but effective.

Answer (score 2):

In Rails 3 you can use an "interceptor" to reroute your development emails as described in [Railscast 206](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/206-action-mailer-in-rails-3).

Answer (score 1):

Devise uses ActionMailer to send emails. In test mode, ActionMailer shouldn't actually send any emails.

Check out [this tutorial](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#example-action-mailer-configuration) for an explanation on ActionMailer and testing environments.

So, depending on the environment, you can basically turn delivery off, while not affecting your actual tests. You just have to specify that option in the `environments/test.rb` file.

Comment: I see that in the test file it has the following code:                  # Tell   Action Mailer not to deliver emails to the real world.
  # The :test delivery method accumulates sent emails in the
  # ActionMailer::Base.deliveries array.
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test  Should I just copy that code snippet to the config/environments/development.rb file

Comment: Hmm even if I do turn the delivery off though wouldn't I still need a way to satisfy the confirmable module, as I would still get the same error that I need to be confirmed.

Comment: If you mean, a way to satisfy it as far as the tests are concerned, I would just fake the confirmation with a mock object, or by just feeding it the confirmation code from the DB, since the delivery of an actual email isn't what's important in the test. What's important is that the confirmation mechanism works, right? That is, when the proper confirmation code is presented via the confirmation URL, you want to know that some kind of `confirmed` flag is flipped in the DB?

Comment: Oh sorry if I wasn't clear I want to skip the confirmation step entirely when working in development, yet still be able to send confirmation e-mails while in production. Right now if I want to sign up a user I can't because of the confirmable module, and I don't know how to skip over that step in development only.

Comment: Ah, so to answer your original question, of whether or not to copy that line of code, I would say sure, give it a shot. The settings are environment-specific. The names of the environments (development/test/whatever) are arbitrary. It's only by convention that they do the same thing from app to app. Technically you could call any/all of your environments whatever you want. It's just NOT recommended to change them because the "Rails way" is "convention over configuration" whenever possible.

Comment: So adding that code snippet did not help, as I get the same issue. One way I think I could solve the issue is with version control by creating a different branch for the confirmable module but I think that is rather clumsy. Or I could just edit the user in my console and set the confirmable attribute to true, but I guess that will just have to do for now.

Comment: I just edited the user in the console in order to bypass the requirement from devise which gave me the result I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Take your model for devise. Commonly Its user.rb. And remove or comment the config **comfirmable**. 
This will prevent the process of confirmation

Answer (score 0):

simmilar to `letter_opener` gem (recommended by [John Beynon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7492286/473040) above) there is a gem called `mailcatcher` which works on SMTP level.

basically you configure SMTP on your Rails app  to point to port under which mailcatcher run on local machine and you have mailcatcher browser on other port to read the emails

more info   https://github.com/sj26/mailcatcher